# How to return total count of the post in 6 different tables

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have 6 different tables as 'mst_article','mst_meetup','mst_question','mst_job','mst_education','mst_event' and I have to return the total count of posts in all these tables with user_id_fk as user_id and status=1. I am using this

```
$u_activity_count = DB::table('mst_article as article','mst_meetup as meetup','mst_question as question','mst_job as job','mst_education as education','mst_event as event')
            ->where('user_id_fk',$user_id)
            ->where('status', '=', '1')
            ->count();
            dd($u_activity_count);
```

but every time it is returning count : 3.
I don't know where I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a raw query which you'd better to always avoid, you can use count() function on the models separately and then add them. Consider something like this:

```
$count = Model::where('user_id_fk', $user_id)->where('status', '1')->count();
```

Comment: Here model refers to which model

Comment: I put Model because I didn't know the names of your models. Basically each of your tables has a corresponding model. So, you can get the count of each of them the way I showed, and then add them together. The sum would be the number that you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this query for getting the total count of posts of multiple tables. My PHP with MySQL code is given below:

```
    // Create connection
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
        // Check connection
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
           die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        } 
        $sql = "Select Sum(count) as totalCount from 
    (
        Select count(*) as count from table1 where user_id_fk=1 and status=1
        Union 
        Select count(*) as count from table2 where user_id_fk=1 and status=1
        Union 
        Select count(*) as count from table3 where user_id_fk=1 and status=1
        Union 
        Select count(*) as count from table4 where user_id_fk=1 and status=1
        Union 
        Select count(*) as count from table5 where user_id_fk=1 and status=1
        Union 
        Select count(*) as count from table6 where user_id_fk=1 and status=1
    ) as f;";
      if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  // Fetch one and one row
  while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result))
    {
    echo 'totalCount='.$row[0];
    }

}
```

If you have any queries, please ask me freely.
Thanks.

Comment: can u provide it for eloquent

Comment: Yes, Can you please tell me which framework you are using?